# Selenium: How to set x and y coordinate position

Tags: selenium

I want to use the Selenium method `mouseMoveAt(java.lang.String locator,java.lang.String coordString)`. How do I set coordString?

For example, if coordString is the x,y position `(10,20)`, what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use following to get element position run time and use them

```
String xCoordinate = selenium.getElementPositionLeft("elementLocator");
String yCoordinate = selenium.getElementPositionTop("elementLocator");
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun , So In this case if I have to move my mouse at particular position i need to store the x,y values in string and then use mouseMoveAt()   similar for clickAt() method etc...

Comment: yup you should try that

Answer (score -2):

The above answer is not a possible solution because selenium.getElementPositionLeft("elementLocator"); returns a number and not a string and not just that it also gives an error which says that we cannot make static reference to non static methods.